# MySQL indexes creation strategy and inner logic

Tags: mysql

This question expects a generic answer to the wide problematic of indexes creation on MySQL database.

Let's take this table example :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `author_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `modificator_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `headline` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url_alias` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `priority` mediumint(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '50',
  `publication_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modification_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Over such a sample there is a wide range of queries that could be performed on different criterions :

- category_id
- published
- publication_date

e.g.:

```
SELECT id FROM article WHERE NOT published AND category_id = '2' ORDER BY publication_date;
```

On many tables you can see a wide range of state fields (like published here), date fields or reference fields (like author_id or category_id). What strategy should be picked to make indexes ?

Which can be developed under the following points:

- Make an index on every fields that can be used in query (either as where argument or order by) even if this can lead to have a lot of indexes per table ?
- Also make an index on fields that have only a small set of values like boolean or enum, this just does reduce the scope size of the scan by a n factor (assuming n being the number of inputs and every value homogeneously used) ?
- I've read that MySQL prior to 5.0 used only one index per request how do the system picks it ? (by choosing the more restrictive one ?)
- How does a OR statement is processed ?
- How much does this is going to slow insert ?
- Does InnoDB/MyISAM change anything to this problem ?

I know the EXPLAIN statement could be used to know whether a request is optimized or not, but a bit of concrete theoretical stuff would really be more constructive than a purely empirical approach !

Comment: Indexes will necessarily be defined for a table's primary and foreign keys and any `UNIQUE` constraints; I'd avoid premature optimisation and only build further indexes to improve the performance of slow queries.